# footer doesn't bind to bottom on small screen

Tags: html, css

I have responsive web page. My problem is that footer ends up in middle of page when it's rendered on small screen device. When I test on devices, which has less than 1200px width, footer ends up just right after screen position. This is what I get on small screen(less than 1200px width):

[image: Fixed size]

And on screen with more than 1200px (this is what I should get on smaller screen devices):
[image: Full size]

Where:

- GREEN - page size
- RED - screen size
- BLUE - footer

And there goes my code:

```
<footer>
    <p>Footer text</p>
<footer>
```

.

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

EDIT: `position: fixed;` doesn't solve since I need it **at bottom of page, not screen.**

Comment: Can you show us your complete code?

Comment: use `position:fixed;`

Comment: I want footer to be at bottom of page, not screen. So `position: fixed` doesn't solve problem

Comment: Have you tried setting footer with position: fixed and a bottom: 0?

Answer (score 1):

```css
footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
   footer {
      position: relative;
   }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p> Footer Text here</p>
</footer>
```

In the example the breaking point is `500px` and not `1200px`. Try resizing your browser window and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve is called sticky footer and it shouldn't be addressed with `position: fixed`. There are other solution that will give you a better results like using Flexbox

The HTML

```
<body class="Site">
  <header>…</header>
  <main class="Site-content">…</main>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

The CSS

```
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

More about it here: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons there was height was set too 100% to devices less than 1200px. CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #base {
        ....
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Removed only this line and everything works. Had page structure like this:

```
<body>
  ....
  <div id="base">
    .....
  </div>
</body>
<footer>..</footer>
```